# Изменение DOM по значению

Tags: jquery

P.s. сори за название, даже не знаю как описать

---

Представим ситуацию:

У нас есть блок в теле которого лежит какое-то количество картинок, допустим это всё выглядит так:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="/img-1.png">
    <img src="/img-2.png">
    <img src="/img-3.png">
    <img src="/img-4.png">
    <img src="/img-5.png">
    <img src="/img-6.png">
    <img src="/img-7.png">
</div>
```

В `div.image` есть атрибут `data-grid` в который мы получаем вот какое-то числовое значение, допустим оно выглядит так `232`.
Думаю понятно что оно означает - это сетка, как должны располагаться картинки внутри блока. Т.е. в нашем случае вот так:
[image]

Вопрос в следующем, как изменять разметку элемента средствами Jquery так, чтобы в конечном результате получать примерно вот такую разметку:

```
<div class="image" data-grid="232">
    <div class="row column-2">
        <img src="/img-1.png">
        <img src="/img-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="row column-3">        
        <img src="/img-3.png">
        <img src="/img-4.png">
        <img src="/img-5.png">
    </div>
    <div class="row column-2">
        <img src="/img-6.png">
        <img src="/img-7.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Естественно, с учётом того, что атрибут `data-grid` может содержать любое количество чисел и разные числа.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код Ваших попыток.

Comment: @Igor, увы, даже не пробовал.. Не могу продумать действия.. В голове только массивы, циклы, но думаю это будет нагружено и лишнее.

Comment: "массивы, циклы" - не лишнее. Или Вы надеетесь на чудо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let image = document.querySelector('.image');

let grid = image.dataset.grid;
    grid = grid.split('');

grid.map( col => {

  let row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row", "column-" + col);
      
  for (col = Number(col); col > 0; col--) {

    row.appendChild(image.firstElementChild);
    
  }
    
  image.appendChild(row);
  
})
```

```css
.image {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.row img {
  background-color: #900;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" data-grid="232">
    <img src="/img-1.png">
    <img src="/img-2.png">
    <img src="/img-3.png">
    <img src="/img-4.png">
    <img src="/img-5.png">
    <img src="/img-6.png">
    <img src="/img-7.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Годно, я думал будет больше строчек кода, спасибо) Но реализую на inline-block)